# Why do I get error when disabling required fields in laravel forms

Tags: laravel

So i have a modal for adding clients into crm that is in Laravel. I deleted required from blade and also from App.js i have some validation rules:

```
$("#commonModalForm").validate({
        rules: {
            client_company_name: "required",
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required",
            email: "required",
        },
```

from here I deleted client_company_name: "required", But when i trying to add new client without that company name field i get the following error in console: POST:https://mydomain/clients?clientresource_id=&clientresource_type= 500 -- vendor.header.js?v=2021-05-11:7

Edit:

Ok i did some more research and I have following error:

Integrity constraint violation: Column cannot be Null

Answer (score 0):

Ok, The problem was the Column type in database it could not have been a NULL value. I changed default value to NULL and it is fixed now